biplot, or plotting a partial RDA with ggplot2. what is not working with the arrows computed with var_fit?
I am trying to plot a partial RDA and some environmental parameters on top of that.
I followed the idea from this post to plot the RDA with ggplot2. I also found this other post which, instead, allows for plotting with base R. I modified it, to add the arrows for environmental parameters.
I am aware of the existence of ggvegan but, even using fortify as suggested, i am unable to get the two plots, in particular the length of the arrows, to match. What am i doing wrong?
If i look at the content of arrows, it looks like ggplot2 is doing it's job. So is it base R that is plotting arrows wrongly?
Here is the code:
library("ggplot2")
library("phyloseq")
library("vegan")
library("scales")

# load data
data(soilrep)

# add some random env vars
meta_data <- as.data.frame(sample_data(soilrep))
meta_data$env_var_one <- sample(100, nrow(meta_data), replace=T)
meta_data$env_var_two <- sample(100, nrow(meta_data), replace=T)
meta_data$env_var_three <- sample(100, nrow(meta_data), replace=T)

set.seed(1)

# compute partial RDA using formula
prda <- ordinate(soilrep, "RDA", formula=as.formula("soilrep~Treatment+warmed+Condition(clipped)"))

# compute fitting
var_fit <- envfit(prda, meta_data[, c("env_var_one", "env_var_two", "env_var_three")], perm=1000, na.rm=TRUE)

# define shapes for treatment legend
shape_legend <- c(15, 16, 17, 18)
# define shapes for treatment in plot
shape <- c(21, 22, 23, 24)
names(shape) <- unique(meta_data$Treatment)

# define colours for warmed
warmed_palette <- hue_pal()(2)[c(2, 1)]
names(warmed_palette) <- c("no", "yes")

# base plotting
dev.new()

par(mar=c(5, 5, 4, 2))
pl <- plot(prda, type="none", scaling=1)
with(meta_data, plot(var_fit, add=T, col="black", p.max=0.99))
with(meta_data, points(prda, "sites", pch=shape[Treatment], bg=warmed_palette[warmed], col="black", scaling=1))
with(meta_data, legend("topright", legend=levels(warmed), fill=warmed_palette, title="warmed"))
with(meta_data, legend("topleft", legend=levels(Treatment), pch=shape_legend, title="Treatment"))

# create data frame for ggplot plotting
# get scores for sites
ggplot_rda <- as.data.frame(vegan::scores(prda, display="sites"))

# add some columns for plotting purposes
ggplot_rda$label <- rownames(ggplot_rda)
ggplot_rda$treatment <- meta_data$Treatment
ggplot_rda$warmed <- meta_data$warmed

# as factor
ggplot_rda$treatment <- factor(ggplot_rda$treatment, levels=unique(ggplot_rda$treatment))
ggplot_rda$warmed <- factor(ggplot_rda$warmed, levels=unique(ggplot_rda$warmed))

# get scores for arrows
arrows <- as.data.frame(vegan::scores(var_fit, display = "vectors"))
arrows$names <- rownames(arrows)

# ggplotting
dev.new()

ggplot(ggplot_rda) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x=RDA1, y=RDA2, fill=warmed, shape=treatment)) +
    coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=shape) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=warmed_palette) +
    geom_segment(data=arrows, aes(x = 0, xend = RDA1, y = 0, yend = RDA2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, "cm"))) +
    geom_text(data=arrows, aes(x = RDA1, y = RDA2, label = names))+
    guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=21)))


You're not fitting a partial RDA there... And I do't understand why you are usingh phyloseq::ordinate() here instead of just calling rda()...

@GavinSimpson, i did use the ordinate function since i am using a phyloseq object, just out of convenience. can i ask you what do you mean when you say i am not fitting a partial RDA?

A partial RDA is one where you remove (partial out) the effects of one or more covariates and then estimate RDA on the residuals. You fit a partial RDA by using Condition() in the formula, for example y ~ x1 + x2 + Condition(block + observer) would estimate the effects of covariates x1 and x2 on the response y after controlling (removing; partialling out) the effects of block and observer.  You're not doing anything like that in the code.

In my Answer, note that I don't do the final thing that plot.envfit does, which is to multiply the coordinates of the arrows after scaling by sqrt(r2) by some multiplier to make the vectors fill the plotting space. I mention that plot.envfit does this but I didn't show it in the code (although one of the other answer does this)

@GavinSimpson you're pefectly right, i am sorry. i copy pasted the wrong code with some mistakes. now it's a partial RDA with correct variables in the formula.

@GavinSimpson, ok, i think i have the solution. however, the answer that do use the multiplier, i think it's using it incorrectly. they do multiply the values twice, one when creating the dataframe, one when plotting with ggplot2. i think multiplying within ggplot2 is not correct. see attached answer.

A partial solution: as mentioned in the comment, to mimic the behaviour of base R, a multiplying factor needs to be computed, to scale the arrows properly. This was also suggested in this answer from the question i linked in the original post.
There is still a problem which i have not solved, though. Base R requires a scaling factor, that can either be 1 or 2. My solution seems to only work with scaling = 2, as i show below. I am not sure why scaling = 1 still is not working but i am investigating.
EDIT: following the comment below, i think i solved the scaling problem. All seems to work now:
# load libraries
library("ggplot2")
library("phyloseq")
library("vegan")
library("scales")

# set scaling factor
scaling_factor <- 1

graphics.off()

# load data
data(soilrep)

# add some random env vars
set.seed(0)
meta_data <- as(sample_data(soilrep), "data.frame")
meta_data$env_var_one <- sample(100, nrow(meta_data), replace=T)
meta_data$env_var_two <- sample(100, nrow(meta_data), replace=T)
meta_data$env_var_three <- sample(100, nrow(meta_data), replace=T)

# compute partial RDA using formula
prda <- ordinate(soilrep, "RDA", formula=as.formula("soilrep~Treatment+warmed+Condition(clipped)"))

# compute fitting
var_fit <- envfit(prda, meta_data[, c("env_var_one", "env_var_two", "env_var_three")], perm=1000, na.rm=TRUE, scaling=scaling_factor)

# define shapes for treatment legend
shape_legend <- c(15, 16, 17, 18)
# define shapes for treatment in plot
shape <- c(21, 22, 23, 24)
names(shape) <- unique(meta_data$Treatment)

# define colours for warmed
warmed_palette <- hue_pal()(2)[c(2, 1)]
names(warmed_palette) <- c("no", "yes")

# set levels
# as factor
meta_data$Treatment <- factor(meta_data$Treatment, levels=unique(meta_data$Treatment))
meta_data$warmed <- factor(meta_data$warmed, levels=unique(meta_data$warmed))

# base plotting
dev.new()

plot(prda, type="none", scaling=scaling_factor)
with(meta_data, plot(var_fit, add=T, col="black", p.max=0.99))
with(meta_data, points(prda, "sites", pch=shape[Treatment], bg=warmed_palette[warmed], col="black", scaling=scaling_factor))
with(meta_data, legend("topright", legend=levels(warmed), fill=warmed_palette, title="warmed"))
with(meta_data, legend("topleft", legend=levels(Treatment), pch=shape_legend, title="Treatment"))

# create data frame for ggplot plotting
# get scores for sites
ggplot_rda <- as.data.frame(vegan::scores(prda, display="sites", scaling=scaling_factor))

# add some columns for plotting purposes
ggplot_rda$label <- rownames(ggplot_rda)
ggplot_rda$treatment <- meta_data$Treatment
ggplot_rda$warmed <- meta_data$warmed

# as factor
ggplot_rda$treatment <- factor(ggplot_rda$treatment, levels=unique(ggplot_rda$treatment))
ggplot_rda$warmed <- factor(ggplot_rda$warmed, levels=unique(ggplot_rda$warmed))

# get multiplying factors for the arrows
arrow_factor <- ordiArrowMul(var_fit)
# get arrows and scale them
arrows <- as.data.frame(vegan::scores(var_fit, display = "vectors"), scaling=scaling_factor) * arrow_factor
arrows$names <- rownames(arrows)

# select arrows which have meaningful p-value, if needed
# for this example, we keep a threshold of 0.99
threshold_p <- 0.99
signif_arrows <- names(which(var_fit$vectors$pvals<=threshold_p))
# subset
print_arrows <- arrows[signif_arrows, ]

# ggplotting
dev.new()

ggplot(ggplot_rda) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x=RDA1, y=RDA2, fill=warmed, shape=treatment)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_shape_manual(values=shape) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=warmed_palette) +
    geom_segment(data=print_arrows, aes(x = 0, xend = RDA1, y = 0, yend = RDA2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, "cm")), colour="black") +
    geom_text(data=print_arrows, aes(x = RDA1, y = RDA2, label = names))+
    guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=21))) +
    theme_bw()

EDIT:
further addition since exporting seems complicated by some other factors that are introduced by plot.envfit as reported in the help page. The problem is that when plotting with base R there is a parameter, i.e. arrow.mul that i think must be set as the arrow factor used to multiply.
From the help(envfit):

The lengths of arrows for fitted vectors are automatically adjusted
for the physical size of the plot, and the arrow lengths cannot be
compared across plots. For similar scaling of arrows, you must
explicitly set the ‘arrow.mul’ argument in the ‘plot’ command; see
‘ordiArrowMul’ and ‘ordiArrowTextXY’.

So this is a solution which will give same plot, no matter which one method (base R or ggplot2) is used:
# load libraries
library("ggplot2")
library("phyloseq")
library("vegan")
library("scales")

# set scaling factor
scaling_factor <- 1

# load data
data(soilrep)

# add some random env vars
set.seed(0)
meta_data <- as(sample_data(soilrep), "data.frame")
meta_data$env_var_one <- sample(100, nrow(meta_data), replace=T)
meta_data$env_var_two <- sample(100, nrow(meta_data), replace=T)
meta_data$env_var_three <- sample(100, nrow(meta_data), replace=T)

# export metadata
write.table(meta_data, "metadata_prints_to_screen.tsv", quote=F, row.names=F, sep="\t")

# compute partial RDA using formula
prda <- ordinate(soilrep, "RDA", formula=as.formula("soilrep~Treatment+warmed+Condition(clipped)"))

# compute fitting
var_fit <- envfit(prda, meta_data[, c("env_var_one", "env_var_two", "env_var_three")], perm=1000, na.rm=TRUE, scaling=scaling_factor)

# get multiplying factors for the arrows
arrow_factor <- ordiArrowMul(var_fit)

# define shapes for treatment legend
shape_legend <- c(15, 16, 17, 18)
# define shapes for treatment in plot
shape <- c(21, 22, 23, 24)
names(shape) <- unique(meta_data$Treatment)

# define colours for warmed
warmed_palette <- hue_pal()(2)[c(2, 1)]
names(warmed_palette) <- c("no", "yes")

# set levels
# as factor
meta_data$Treatment <- factor(meta_data$Treatment, levels=unique(meta_data$Treatment))
meta_data$warmed <- factor(meta_data$warmed, levels=unique(meta_data$warmed))

# new dev
dev.new()

# plot with base R
plot(prda, type="none", scaling=scaling_factor)
with(meta_data, plot(var_fit, add=T, col="black", p.max=0.99, arrow.mul=arrow_factor))
with(meta_data, points(prda, "sites", pch=shape[Treatment], bg=warmed_palette[warmed], col="black", scaling=scaling_factor))
with(meta_data, legend("topright", legend=levels(warmed), fill=warmed_palette, title="warmed"))
with(meta_data, legend("topleft", legend=levels(Treatment), pch=shape_legend, title="Treatment"))

# create data frame for ggplot plotting
# get scores for sites
ggplot_rda <- as.data.frame(vegan::scores(prda, display="sites", scaling=scaling_factor))

# add some columns for plotting purposes
ggplot_rda$label <- rownames(ggplot_rda)
ggplot_rda$treatment <- meta_data$Treatment
ggplot_rda$warmed <- meta_data$warmed

# as factor
ggplot_rda$treatment <- factor(ggplot_rda$treatment, levels=unique(ggplot_rda$treatment))
ggplot_rda$warmed <- factor(ggplot_rda$warmed, levels=unique(ggplot_rda$warmed))

# get arrows and scale them
arrows <- as.data.frame(vegan::scores(var_fit, display = "vectors"), scaling=scaling_factor) * arrow_factor
arrows$names <- rownames(arrows)

# select arrows which have meaningful p-value, if needed
# for this example, we keep a threshold of 0.99
threshold_p <- 0.99
signif_arrows <- names(which(var_fit$vectors$pvals<=threshold_p))
# subset
print_arrows <- arrows[signif_arrows, ]

# make the plot
export_ggplot <- ggplot(ggplot_rda) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x=RDA1, y=RDA2, fill=warmed, shape=treatment)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_shape_manual(values=shape) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=warmed_palette) +
    geom_segment(data=print_arrows, aes(x = 0, xend = RDA1, y = 0, yend = RDA2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, "cm")), colour="black") +
    geom_text(data=print_arrows, aes(x = RDA1, y = RDA2, label = names))+
    guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=21))) +
    theme_bw()

# new dev
dev.new()
plot(export_ggplot)


I suspect the fact that scaling = 1 isn't working for you is because you only specify this scaling once. When you extract the scores to form ggplot_rda initially, you don't specify the scaling to use so it uses the default, which is 2. But this also means that all your other code is wrong as you need to specify scaling in all calls to plot() points(), etc.

@GavinSimpson i added this to the code. seems like it's working now.
