How to use plot.metaMDS
I have result of a NMDS using metaMDS() and I would like to plot my species ordination plot using a grouping variable in my environmental data.
So I am wondering what determines the colour of the species points when you plot your NMDS result against an environmental variable used to colour these points? Here's some of my code:
nmds_result2 <- metaMDS(my_matrix_merged_simple.taxa_filtered_clean, distance = "bray", k=3, autotransform = TRUE)

plot(nmds_result2, type = "n")
points(nmds_result2, display = "species", col = as.factor(envar1_merged_simple.taxa$gp), pch = 16)
legend("bottomleft", legend = levels(grouping), col = 1:length(levels(envar1_merged_simple.taxa$gp)), pch = 16)


When I do this currently, my plot gives colours to the species points, but I was expecting that because the species are almost all shared among each level of the grouping variable, that each point should have three colours associated with it. I asked chatGPT to give me a jitter option, and after that, I found that there are not any overlapping points.
Example data:
> nmds_scores_species
                       NMDS1      NMDS2       NMDS3
Arachnida        -0.35591394 -0.2908162  0.86212875
Araneae           0.79063822  0.1772402 -0.83735656
Coleoptera        0.25628351 -1.0305379  0.35936734
Diptera           0.18070607 -0.5229378 -0.81037545
Entomobryomorpha -0.64149631  0.1478419  0.10525228
Gastropoda        0.06480422  0.9302620 -0.87786281
Geophilomorpha    0.06978459  0.1640539 -0.94725257
Hymenoptera       0.87234106 -1.6514856 -0.80499852
larvae           -0.32263355 -0.8209021 -0.43266790
Lepidoptera      -2.19411334  1.0306287 -0.59109150
Oribatida         0.62006068  0.3603857  0.27795806
Psocodea         -0.73203928  0.5296178 -0.08390503

> levels(envar1_merged_simple.taxa$gp)
[1] "Collected"   "Observed"    "OldObserved"




there are not data to replicate your results so it's difficult to answer appropriately. anyways: if you're using phyloseq this link may help: https://joey711.github.io/phyloseq/plot_ordination-examples.html
or you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711470/plotting-envfit-vectors-vegan-package-in-ggplot2, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711470/plotting-envfit-vectors-vegan-package-in-ggplot2/61912583,
or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78677348/biplot-or-plotting-a-partial-rda-with-ggplot2-what-is-not-working-with-the-arr
